# Tomcat: how does Tomcat unloads classes internally?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, osgi, classloader

I am looking for a way to replace a jar with old functionality with a new one without stopping the whole application. I have googled for this a little bit ([Unloading classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java), [Dynamically loadable and unloadable application modules in Java - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486903/dynamically-loadable-and-unloadable-application-modules-in-java-how)), and have found 3 possible solutions:

1. OSGI, which looks too complicated for my purposes: class unloading is the only thing I need from this powerful specification.
2. Own implementation, which implies creating own Classloader, loading jars with its help, and when time comes to dismiss the jar - expose Classloader instance to GC and hope that GC will remove it together with all loaded jars, which may not happen immediately.
3. Copy the stuff application servers do :) That is the purpose of my question.

**Is there any explanation on how Tomcat unloads the classes (wars)? Is it possible to reuse this in my application?**

PS
Just while I was writing this post 2 strange ideas came into my head:

1. may be we can start another instance of application with new set of jars and switch input and output data flows from old one to new one. If there is a place to preserve state - it can be more quick than full restart.
2. may be Spring may help? It can dynamically register beans, but this looks like somewhat ugly solution, and it cannot unload them anyway; may be, Spring Boot may help?

Comment: OSGi may appear complicated because it has to handle a lot of corner cases. If you go route 2 or 3, you are likely to end up reimplementing a significant portion of OSGi -- except without the benefit of our 18 years experience doing this :-)

Answer (score 2):

A class can be unloaded only when it and its class loader are unreachable and thus eligible for garbage collection. Since the class loader can reach every class it loaded and every class loaded by a class loader can reach its class loader and every object which is an instance of a class can reach its class, this means that the class loader, all the classes it loaded and all the objects which are an instance of those classes must *all* be unreachable and eligible to be garbage collected. Only then, can a class be "unloaded" when that complete object graph is garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

I can only partially answer you questions, however better than nothing... You are right, modularity is a quite a tedious topic (at least until there's Java 9).

Ad idea 2 (Spring): I already spent some thoughts on Spring Boot [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953635/is-there-a-pattern-for-dynamically-loadable-modules-in-spring-boot/39964261#39964261) and came to the conclusion that I'll stick either to OSGI (it's worth getting into it) or to a pure Microservice architecture.

Comment: Modularity will be a tedious topic in Java 9 too. There is no magic fairy dust coming in Java 9. :-)

Answer (score 1):

- I suppose that you are not doing whole redeployment of application, but don't want to restart whole application every time while you are developing it
- If you want to change functionality of methods without changing class or method signatures you can use Spring Loaded
- Add dependency to your project https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/springloaded/1.2.6.RELEASE
- Set JVM option -javaagent:path\springloaded-version.jar -noverify

  - This option can be set in several ways depending on how you run tomcat
  - I have Broadleaf eccomerce web site and I added this option to MAVEN_OPTS in batch script that runs embedded tomcat or you can configure that in Run configuration for Tomcat VM options
- read http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html

Comment: Thanks, Zildyan! As far as I understand this relates to hotswapping techniques. But I am interested more in loading/unloading techniques. The difference is that hotswapping replaces some class instance in memory, while I want to add it and remove it completely.